# Botão para selecionar qual carrossel exibir

Tags: javascript, html, css

Criei dois carrossel um de Ilustração e outro de Planta de uma casa, e preciso de dois botões, Ilustração e Planta, ao carregar a pagina, irá mostrar o carrossel ilustração como principal, e ao clicar no carrossel de planta deve ocultar ilustração, e assim vice versa.

**Exemplo:**

```
<button class="ative btn btn-outline-info">ILUSTRAÇÃO</button>
<button class="ative btn btn-outline-info">PLANTAS</button>

<div id="bannerIluminacao" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
         <img class="d-block w-100" src="Imagem.png"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Código de plantas:**

```
<div id="bannerPlantas" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
         <img class="d-block w-100" src="Imagem.png"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode incluir no button uma classe genérica para identificar o clique e um atributo "data" identificando qual deve ser o carrossel a ser mostrado, exemplo:

```
<button class="ative btn btn-outline-info showCarousel" data-id="ilustracao">ILUSTRAÇÃO</button>
<button class="ative btn btn-outline-info showCarousel" data-id="plantas">PLANTAS</button>

<div id="bannerIluminacao" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
         <img class="d-block w-100" src="Imagem.png"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div> 

<div id="bannerPlantas" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
         <img class="d-block w-100" src="Imagem.png"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".showCarousel").on("click",function(e){
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            if(id == "ilustracao")
            {
                $("#bannerIluminacao").show();
                $("#bannerPlantas").hide();
            }
            else
            {
                $("#bannerPlantas").show();
                $("#bannerIluminacao").hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Obrigado brother, funcionou perfeitamente, porém estou com um pequeno probleminha, tenho 5 modais na mesmo arquivo, porém ao clicar para abrir eles está com um pequeno bug, as duas imagens do botão abrem junto, e quando clicar no botão mostra a do desejado (e fica mostrando apenas uma), no caso um botão deverá abrir ativado. Obs.: Tõ pesquisando a respeito já pra encontrar, mas se tiver como me ajudar mais uma vez eu agradeço :-)

Answer (score 1):

**OBS:** Reparei que existe uma tag `</div>` de fechamento a mais no seu código! Recomento remover essa tag após a imagem! `<img class="d-block w-100" src="Imagem.png"></div>`

Fiz um exemplo básico ***apenas com CSS***, mas dependendo da sua estrutura do HTML pode precisar de algum JS. De qualquer forma segue um exemplo funcionando para vc ver.

Repare que os seletores " **~** " e " **+** " precisam de uma determinada estrutura de HTML porque que a div o `.carousel` está no mesmo *nível* dos `inputs` e o CSS atinja elas. *(qq dúvida é só perguntar)*

Veja o modelo funcionando. O pulo do gato aqui é usar um "rádio button" escondido para alternar entre uma `div` e outra.

```css
.carousel {
    margin-top: 20px;
    transition: 350ms;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
#ilustra:checked ~ #bannerIluminacao.carousel, #planta:checked ~ #bannerPlantas.carousel {
    opacity: 1;
}

input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100px;   
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 350ms
}
#ilustra:checked + label, #planta:checked + label {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="ilustra" checked>
<label for="ilustra">Ilustração</label>
<input type="radio" name="slider" id="planta">
<label for="planta">Planta</label>

<div id="bannerIluminacao" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://unsplash.it/200/200">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="bannerPlantas" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://baconmockup.com/200/200">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**OBS:** Não precisei mexer no seu HTML, só acrescentei os `labels` e `inputs` e o CSS deles.

Comment: Brother, preciso de um script ou até mesmo atributo html, para quando carregar a pagina exibir apenas o primeiro carrossel, está sempre abrindo os dois, usei o exemplo do Gabriel por usar JS achei mais fácil! desde obrigado.

Comment: Tranquilo jovem! Foi só um exemplo usando só CSS mesmo, nem sempre ele encaixa no projeto. Tmj

Comment: Tõ com um pequeno bug, na parte de abrir o modal, está abrindo os dois carrossel junto... teria como me ajudar? Veja ai na parte de empreendimentos http://mmssistemas.esy.es/Ilhc/index.php

Comment: Marcos eu não sou muito bom de JS, mas o que posso te dizer é que existem 9 elementos na sua página com o mesmo ID **id="exampleModalLabel"** isso com certeza está errado! Pois o ID só pode ter um nome único e não ser usado em vários elementos!

Comment: Sugiro vc criar uma **Nova Pergunta** com esse problema em específico, assim fica mais fácil pro pessoal ajudar etc...